# The positive-definite QP minimal solution does not equal to Lagrangean multiplier solution

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Have a  positive-definite QP ($\varLambda$ is positive-definite, $A$ is full row rank ):

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
&min \quad f(x)=c^{T} \varLambda c + k^{T}c \\
&s.t. \quad Ac-b=0 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Use Lagrangean multiplier

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
&L(c,\alpha) = c^{T} \varLambda c + \alpha^{T} (Ac-b) \\
&\bigtriangledown_{c}L= \varLambda c + k + A^{T}\alpha = 0 \\
&\bigtriangledown_{\alpha}L = Ac-b=0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Then the $c_{min}$ can represent
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
&\alpha= (-A \varLambda^{-1}A^{T})^{-1}(A \varLambda^{-1}k + b)\\
&c_{min} = -\varLambda^{-1}(k+A^{T} \alpha)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
This soluton $c_{min}$ should be the minial solution of QP but I feel confused  when i use  Moore–Penrose inverse to solve $ Ac=b$ and put the solution ($c_{m-p}$) to the object function. Somtime the $f(c_{m-p})<f(c_{min})$ is happend. Why?

ex:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
&min \quad f(x)=c^{T} 
\begin{pmatrix}  
    0.54534832 & 0\\
    0 & 0.15573046\\  \end{pmatrix} 
    c + 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1.86544158 & 6.19765616
\end{pmatrix} 
    c \\
&s.t. \quad 
\begin{pmatrix}
   8.53061926 & 2.34567083
\end{pmatrix}
c- 3.84608369 = 0\\
& c_{min} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
   8.29260734 \\ -28.51849082
\end{pmatrix}  \quad  f(c_{min}) =2.879981 \\ 
 & c_{m-p} =
\begin{pmatrix}
   0.41916381 \\ 0.11525779
\end{pmatrix} \quad  f(c_{m-p}) =1.594139 \\  
&\color{red}{f(c_{m-p})<f(c_{min})}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your computation:

$$\bigtriangledown_c L = \color{red}2\Lambda c + k + A^T\alpha=0$$